# React useContext doesn't work using setTimeout function to update the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am new to React, so maybe excuse my dumb question. I want to refresh the score of my card game in a for Each loop with a setTimeout function in each run. The state seems to be updated, but the DOM (Component overarching) is not.

```
export function RefillStack() {
  const { gameStore, setGameStore } = useContext(GameContext);
  const finishMove = () => {
    let game: Game = { ...gameStore };
      // some code
    game.players.forEach((player, playerIndex) => {
      game.players[playerIndex] = player.cards.filter(card => card > 6);
      // some code
      setTimeout(()=> {setGameStore(game)}, 1000);
    });
```

If I use the useState function then everything works, but I have to use the useContext function. I think I need a workaround for this, but what is the smartest way to do it? Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Can u post the code for your `GameContext`? using the React Context Api requires a special setup, including the Provider Component.  It's not clear here what you are trying to do, although `setTimeout(()=> {setGameStore(game)}, 1000);` already seems wrong because you seem to be feeding `game` to its own context in a loop, which is most probably not what you want

Answer (score 0):

I have come closer to my solution myself.

I had to assign a clone of the gameStore to the variable "Game" again after the setGameState function.

It's certainly not elegant, but it works for me. The forEach looks now like this.

```
 game.players.forEach((player, playerIndex) => {
  game.players[playerIndex] = player.cards.filter(card => card > 6);
  // some code
  setTimeout(()=> {setGameStore(game)}, 1000 * (playerIndex + 1));
  game = {...gameStore};
});
```